# Error ondelete cascade sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Estou com error quando vou fazer a exclusão em cascata , usando postgres sequelize na versão 6.

> original: error: update or delete on table "Users" violates foreign
> key constraint "Tarefas_UserId_fkey" on table "Tarefas.

***MODEL USER***

```
class Users extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Users.hasMany(models.Tarefas, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE', 
        foreignKey: { allowNull: false } ,
        hooks: true
      });
    }
  };
  Users.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    sobrenome: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    typeuser: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Users',
  });
  return Users;
```

***MODEL TAREFAS***

```
 class Tarefas extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {

      
     Tarefas.belongsTo(models.Users); 
    }
  };


  Tarefas.init({
    nome: DataTypes.STRING,
    valor: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    local: DataTypes.STRING,
    data:DataTypes.DATE,
    status:DataTypes.REAL

  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Tarefas',
  });
  return Tarefas;
```

***NA MINHA MIGRATE TAREFA ADICIONEI***

```
 UserId:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
        defaultValue:0,
        references:{
          model:'Users',
          key:'id'
        }
        
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

resolvei da seguinte maneira na minha migrate Tarefas no atributo UserId coloquei uma propriedade onDelete: 'CASCADE'. por mais que colocasse isso direto na model não funciona comforme a documentação.

*Uei o mysql e postgres e funcionou de boa.*

```
UserId:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
        defaultValue:0,
        references:{
          model:'Users',
          key:'id'
        },

        onDelete:'CASCADE'
      }
```